# Combine array elements into single string

Tags: php, arrays

So this is what I'm trying to do..

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `members";
while($rew = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $var[] =",'".$rew['username']."'";
}
print_r ($var)
```

So I get the result:

```
Array ( [0] => ",'John'", [1] => ",'Mason'", [2] => ",'Greg'", [3] => ",'Paul'" )
```

So now I want the variable to display all results when I echo. For example:

```
<?php echo $var[1] ?>
```

And the result will be just `,'Mason'`.

How do I get it so that I can echo $var[*] and get all the results. "John,Mason,Greg,Paul".

I have been trying to figure this out for a very long time and is getting very frustrating for me. Can someone please help me.

Comment: How does the title relate to the question?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when asking your question. It won't get you attention any more quickly, and it makes your subject harder to read. It also wastes the time of people who have to edit to fix it, and they could be using that time to try and help answer questions. Thanks. :)

Comment: @ZianChoy: Just changed it to better reflect the intent.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to the site, but have been browsing on it for sometime. I really appreciate the help.  Sorry again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.

```
<?php echo implode(",", $var) ?>
```

And change your loop code to:

```
$var[] = $rew['username'];
```

Comment: It actually appears that his loop already appends the comma to the beginning. So each item would be in the format `,'Name'`.

Comment: @animuson: Just noticed that myself. Amended my answer.

Comment: I really appreciate you're help. This worked! Thank you so much, and the others as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use echo on an array directly.  You could either loop through the array using a control structure like *for* or *foreach*, or you can use a built-in function that is designed to operate on arrays.  To get the output you are looking for try:

```
<?php echo implode(',', $var);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good tutorial: [Tizag - MySQL Fetch Array](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlfetcharray.php)

This should work:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `members`"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['username'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your loop to something like:

```
$var = "";
while($rew = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  $var .= ",'" . $rew['username'] . "'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one liner that also adds the quotes

```
<?php echo "'" . implode("','", $var) . "'"; ?>
```

and if you use pdo, you can get the usernames even easier

```
<?php
$usernames = $db->query("SELECT username FROM members")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
echo "'" . implode("','", $usernames) . "'";
?>
```